# How to convert an integer to a character array using C

Tags: c

I want to convert an integer number to a character array in C.

Input:

```
int num = 221234;
```

The result is equivalent to:

```
char arr[6];
arr[0] = '2';
arr[1] = '2';
arr[2] = '1';
arr[3] = '2';
arr[4] = '3';
arr[5] = '4';
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I suggect that you use Google before asking something on here.

Comment: [man sprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Make use of the `log10` function to determine the number of digits and do like below:

```
char * toArray(int number)
{
    int n = log10(number) + 1;
    int i;
    char *numberArray = calloc(n, sizeof(char));
    for (i = n-1; i >= 0; --i, number /= 10)
    {
        numberArray[i] = (number % 10) + '0';
    }
    return numberArray;
}
```

Or the other option is `sprintf(yourCharArray,"%ld", intNumber);`

Comment: so , isn't there a less time consuming solution as i have to make the algorithm  which works in less than 1 sec

Comment: I think `floor()` is necessary around `log10(number)` to avoid rounding error... but I'm not sure... anyways +1 good answer

Comment: Is not this return a reverse number?

Comment: You have 4 issues with your approach: 1. you didn't allocated enough space for NULL character; 2. the output char is NOT ASCII, but INT; 3. if you input 0 (zero), it returns nothing; 4. the output string is reversed

Comment: Change the for loop to ```for ( i = n-1; i >= 0; --i, number /= 10 )``` so the output isn't reversed and the line in the loop to be ```numberArray[i] = (number % 10)+'0';``` to convert the int to a char.

Answer (score 28):

'[sprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf)' will work fine, if your first argument is a pointer to a character (a pointer to a character is an array in 'c'), you'll have to make sure you have enough space for all the digits and a terminating '\0'.
For example, If an integer uses 32 bits, it has up to 10 decimal digits.
So your code should look like:

```
int i;
char s[11]; 
...
sprintf(s,"%ld", i);
```

Answer (score 3):

The *easy* way is by using `sprintf`.  I know others have suggested `itoa`, but a) it isn't part of the standard library, and b) `sprintf` gives you formatting options that `itoa` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Use itoa, as is shown [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/11049/convert-int-to-string#).

```
char buf[5];
// Convert 123 to string [buf]
itoa(123, buf, 10);
```

`buf` will be a string array as you documented. You might need to increase the size of the buffer.

Comment: `itoa` is not a standard C function, it will not be present on all implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You may give a shot at using [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/). Another alternative is to use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/).

Comment: http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/cplusplus.com

Comment: @StoryTeller it seems I am not able to access this link.

Comment: It's a list of reasons why cplusplus (dot) com is bad as a reference site.

Comment: @StoryTeller well I use it for function definitions and for most standard functions I find it useful enough. In this particular case I believe both functions I linked to are well described there.

Comment: But it may teach newcomer some bad habits. Many of its examples show `using namesapce std;` for instance. http://en.cppreference.com/w/ is a community managed reference, as accurate if not more, and without the poor habits in the examples.